# What is the best way to parse a string from an array to a dictionary?

Tags: arrays, bash, dictionary

I receive from "[somewhere](https://dartcode.org/docs/using-dart-define-in-flutter/)" an array of stuff that looks like a dictionary
and I need to access the value of a specific one (e.g. the value for the key "FOO")
what is the best way to access it?

Do I need to "parse" the string (or whatever it is) to dictionary or I have a shortcut?

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# GNU bash, version 4.4.20

ARR=(FOO='hello' BAR='world')

for index in "${!ARR[@]}" 
do  
    echo "${index}"

    I_WISH_WAS_A_DICTIONARY=${ARR[$index]}
    
    echo "${I_WISH_WAS_A_DICTIONARY}"

     if [ -v ${I_WISH_WAS_A_DICTIONARY[FOO]} ]; then       
        break
     fi 
     
done
```

here is a [runnable code sample](https://rextester.com/IKQY17471)

*note about foo bar syntax*:

I do not have control over the syntax of `FOO='hello', BAR='world'`
in the real world those come from [dart define](https://dartcode.org/docs/using-dart-define-in-flutter/)
I'm trying to use those in running a "Pre-action" script on a iOS build

```bash
function entry_decode() { echo "${*}" | base64 --decode; }

IFS=',' read -r -a define_items <<< "$DART_DEFINES"


for index in "${!define_items[@]}"
do
    define_items[$index]=$(entry_decode "${define_items[$index]}");
done
```

Comment: That's JSON, use the `jq` utility to parse it.

Comment: is it? jq command throws on it... it's also not an associative array as it misses some brackets`([FOO]='hello'` and commma(s)

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that it doesn't have `{}` around the whole thing to make a JSON object. You could try wrapping it in that before calling `jq`.

Comment: If you define `arr` with `declare -A arr=([FOO]="hello" [BAR]="world" )` then `for index in "${!arr[@]}"; do printf '%s=%s\n' "$index" "${arr[$index]}"; done` (for instance) works.  See [BashGuide/Arrays - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) for information about Bash associative arrays.  See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/4154375) for an explanation of why I replaced `ARR` with `arr`.

Comment: Is `FOO='hello' BAR='world'` the output of some command?

Comment: @pjh I don't have control over foo bar

Comment: @Fravadona is correct: those come from a command,   added some "note about foo bar syntax" in the initial question

Comment: Does IOS have bash >= 4? If not, then there's no dictionary structure in bash 3

Comment: Does this do anything like what you want: `arr=(FOO='hello' BAR='world'); searchkey=FOO; for kv in "${arr[@]}"; do k=${kv%%=*}; v=${kv#*=}; if [[ $k == "$searchkey" ]]; then printf '%s=%s\n' "$k" "$v"; break; fi; done` ?

Comment: 3.2 :( good catch @Fravadona I'll try to handle it with some string juggling  than :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Fravadona for pointing out the limitation of bash on iOS.
Here is a possible solution for whoever may end up in my shoes in the future.

```bash
ARR=(FOO=hello BAR=world)
KEY='FOO'
for DEFINE in ${ARR[@]}
do 
    echo $DEFINE
   IFS='=' read -r K V <<< $DEFINE
   if [ $K = $KEY ]; 
   then
        echo $V
        break
   fi
done
```